# div to float left

Tags: css

I am weak in css and can you please help with this problem. You can see problem by clicking on Login/Register link in the below url.

[Test box url](http://techmasti.forwardsfarm.com/)

This is done in drupal. I am not able get the css to make the div with id "toboggan-login" to appear under the "Login/Register" link

Forgot to mention. I put the below css code. It works in small resolution systems. But its does not work in my 22'' monitor.

```
div#toboggan-login {
position: absolute;
top: 23px;
left: 74em;
}
```

Comment: i don't see the problem?

Comment: It is under it..? http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/6929/under.png

Comment: I just updated the question. I works in my laptop but its not working in my monitor which is 1920x1080. You can the image here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/testma.png/

Comment: There is no need to tag a question title as solved. That's the whole purpose of marking an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will fix your issue:

CSS:

```
div#toboggan-login {
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 310px;
    width: 160px;
}
```

Than if you want to distance it a bit from the Login/Register top, just add:

`top:10px;` or how much `px` you want!

---

To explain the above lines:

The `left:50%;` pushes your element in the middle of the screen, so even at window resize your element will stay there, centered.
But to set it appropriately to some center-left position than we add `position-left` that will adjust the element position to a desired amount of `px` left from the center.

Comment: thanks @roXon i think missed left:50% trick. I don't have my laptop around, but I think its should work fine.

Comment: @Shyam, I tested it directly in your page using Firebug. So: it will work. Thanks!